# wordpress url with format .com/category/sub-category

Tags: urls

I may be overlooking a simple answer here, but this one is stumping me. I am converting a site to wordpress. The current site has many pages whose URL has the format www.x.com/category/topic.

What I cant figure out/remember, is how to create a page or post with that format. As far as I know, the standard wordpress format is www.x.com/category

It is important to keep the integrity of these links, so keeping the exact destinations is a must. I would like to accomplish this without the use of redirection plugins.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If "topic" is some particular category then what you are describing is the default category structure. Please try to make it more clear what have and want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [structure tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Structure_Tags) in `Settings` > `Permalinks` > `Custom Structure` to form something like `/%category%/%postname%/`.

That is if your "topics" will be posts. Pages or terms might be more involved to deal with.

Comment: And if you want to get rid of the category base the easiest way is probably to install this plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-no-category-base/